# Cannot export firebase-admin's initializeApp function

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

In an attempt to abstract the `firebase-admin` dependency, I have a file `index.js` that is meant to export the functionality my project uses. Why is it not possible to export the `initializeApp` as a property?

For example:

index.js

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.initializeApp = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp;
```

consumer.js

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('path/to/index.js');

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();
```

The following error is thrown:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined

In an attempt to isolate the issue, I wrote the following to prove that `initializeApp` cannot be exported as a property, as I've done with other functions:

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');

const initializeApp = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp;

initializeApp();
```

This throws:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'INTERNAL' of undefined

Why can I not export `initializeApp` as a property? This error has forced me to rewrite the export in index.js to:

```
exports.initializeApp = () => firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();
```

But this feels like a hack.

Does it make a difference that every one of my files starts with `'use strict;'`? That would be surprising.

Comment: If you're already exporting the initialized Firebase App by this line `exports.initializeApp = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp;`, then why are you trying to initialize it again in this line `const initializeApp = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp;` which means you're trying to do `firebaseAdmin.initializeApp.initializeApp`? You already have the initialized app, just try to use it directly as `firebaseAdmin()`. Also, if you're using it in your backend, then you can set it as `app.set('firebaseAdmin', admin)` and use it as `req.app.get('firebaseAdmin')` without exporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of how the Admin SDK is implemented. The main export of the Admin SDK package is not a real module, but an instance of a class. So when you extract a single method from that class instance, it looses all its context, and internal references like `this` starts malfunctioning. Here's a simplistic example to illustrate the problem.

```
// file: sdk.ts
class Firebase {
  public INSTANCE = {key: 'sdk'};

  public initializeApp() {
    console.log('Initializing', this.INSTANCE['key']);
  }
}

const admin = new Firebase();
export = admin;
```

```
# File: test.js
// admin actually points to an instance of the Firebase class
const admin = require('./sdk');

// extract a single method from the object instance
const initializeApp = admin.initializeApp;

// The "this" reference in the initializeApp method no longer works
initializeApp();
```

You will have to continue  using the workaround you've found for now. It might get addressed in a future release of the SDK, but right now it's not supported.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. How do you check if a dependency's function references `this`? Figuring the simple answer is "check source code and/or wait for an error". But, is there is a more efficient approach you can recommend?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think it's best to avoid doing that kind of checks anyway since a library might change how its APIs are implemented. A method that doesn't use `this` today, might do so tomorrow. Just assume it's not supported, and write your code to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In **Typescript**, Use as follows:

```js
import { App, ServiceAccount, initializeApp, cert } from "firebase-admin/app";
import * as serviceAccount from "./service-account.json";

initializeApp({
   credential: cert( serviceAccount as ServiceAccount ),
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/593